# Page takes time to load due to script when there are more than 9 same scripts

Tags: javascript, jsp

Observed that page takes too much time to load due to the script, I have similar 8-9 scripts on page, how to avoid script loading.

This a simple script to open pop up which can used for static and dynamic content.

```
               <script> $(function () {
            $("#LoginOpener").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                height: 350,
                resizable: false,
                modal: true,
                minHeight: 250,`enter code here`
                delay: 5000,
                open: function (event, ui) {
                    $(event.target).dialog('widget')
                            .css({position: 'fixed'})
                            .position({my: 'center', at: 'center', of: window});
                    $('.test').addClass('test');

                },
                width: 600,
                show: {
                    duration: 1000
                },
                hide: {
                    duration: 1000
                }
            });
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                cache: false,
                url: "pagename.jsp"
            });

            $(".LoginOpener").click(function () {
                $("#LoginOpener").dialog("open");

            });

            function closeCommentPopup()
            {
                $("#LoginOpener").dialog("close");
            }
        }); <script>
```

Comment: Is the script loaded when the page is loaded or after it is loaded? Maybe the script depends on other functions that need to be loaded, so it takes some time.

Comment: Script loaded during page laod...I verified by injecting alert ...I need to stop loading of this script on page load and should load on click. I tried adding declaring variable for function but that is also not working :(

Comment: Have you considered using the following?
 `$(document).ready(function(){/*your methods to execute*/ });`
So you can let everything load and after everything is loaded, your function can start working.

Comment: thanks it worked with iFrame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it ..it was due to "<%@include file="pagename.jsp" %>". So page always considers everything pagename.jsp during load. Hence it was loading.

Handled include through iFrame. It worked.